# Do mel-spectrograms of two audios have linear property?

Tags: spectrogram

Suppose I have an audio and some noise, and want to do data augmentation for analysis.

Since each audio and noise can have corresponding mel-spectrogram, instead of computing the mel-spectrogram of the wav form of audio + noise, is it sufficient for just adding-up the mel-spectrograms of audio and noise?

Any mathematical justification of proving/disproving linearity is super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Mel-spectrogram is the projection of spectrogram, $|\text{STFT}|$ or  $|\text{STFT}|^2$, onto mel basis. Linearity is lost at modulus: $|\text{STFT}(x_0)| + |\text{STFT}(x_1)| \neq |\text{STFT}(x_0 + x_1)|$.

However, one can *first* combine the $\text{STFT}$'s, which are themselves linear and so is their sum, and *then* project them: this is same as mel-spectrogram of combined input.

Brief math: STFT is convolution with windowed complex sinusoids, and convolution is linear: $h \star x_0 + h \star x_1 = h \star (x_0 + x_1)$. The mel projection step is also linear.

Demo below.

```
import numpy as np
import librosa

#%% Direct mel #################################
kw = dict(sr=22050, n_fft=2048)  # defaults
x0 = np.random.randn(4096)
x1 = np.random.randn(4096)
M0 = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(x0, **kw)
M1 = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(x1, **kw)
M  = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(x0 + x1, **kw)
assert not np.allclose(M0 + M1, M)

#%% Direct STFT ################################
S0 = librosa.stft(x0,      n_fft=kw['n_fft'])
S1 = librosa.stft(x1,      n_fft=kw['n_fft'])
S  = librosa.stft(x0 + x1, n_fft=kw['n_fft'])
assert np.allclose(S0 + S1, S)

#%% Mel, first combine STFT ####################
mel_basis = librosa.filters.mel(**kw)
MS01 = np.dot(mel_basis, np.abs(S0 + S1)**2)
assert np.allclose(MS01, M)
```

Comment: Really appreciate about the demo and explanation as well!